# What was the last message to Opportunity today (13 Feb '19)?

Tags: mars, communication, rovers, opportunity, mars-exploration-rover

Several articles have mentioned that the last ever commands were sent to the unresponsive Opportunity rover today by NASA.  Now, I know that it wasn't a verbal message, but was there anything digital sent that was sentimental or meaningful that appeals to our emotions (easter eggs)?  Or was it the electronic equivalent of "turn off"?

Comment: All I can guess is that it probably wasn't "thanks for all the fish"

Comment: @uhoh not too far off, to be honest hah!

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34243/198

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From [ArsTechnica](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/02/opportunity-did-not-answer-nasas-final-call-and-its-now-gone-to-us/):

> Late Tuesday night, scientists at NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory sent their final data uplink to the Opportunity rover on Mars. Over this connection, via the Deep Space Network, the American jazz singer Billie Holiday crooned "I'll Be Seeing You," a song that closes with the lines:
>
> *I'll find you in the morning sun*
>
> *And when the night is new I'll be*
>
> *looking at the moon*
>
> *But I'll be seeing you*

[I'll be seeing you by Billie Holiday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDlKb2cBAqU)

*Now if you excuse me, I have something in my eye...*

Comment: ...apparently there *absolutely was* some indication!

Comment: Yep, now I feel bad for a robot.

Comment: It's now joined [Cassini](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2017/09/15/meanwhile-on-mars-13-cassini/) in robot heaven...

Comment: Thanks for this. Um. I had to go stand in the kitchen for a minute.

Comment: that's just bizarre, they sent an mp3 audio file ?

Comment: It is not so bad, ten years on the Mars while three months was expected...

Comment: @Fattie [How did NASA's Deep Space Network encode and broadcast music to Opportunity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34185/12102)

Comment: @Ingolifs It seems that the article is not totally accurate, the music was [never sent over the DSN](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34705/18663)