# How many non-crewed deep-space destinations have had intentional broadcasts of music from Earth?

Tags: radio-communication, space-art, space-agencies, audio

@Ingolifs's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34184/12102) to the question *What was the last message to Opportunity today (13 Feb '19)?* quotes ArsTechnica's [Opportunity did not answer NASA’s final call, and it’s now lost to us](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/02/opportunity-did-not-answer-nasas-final-call-and-its-now-gone-to-us/):

> Late Tuesday night, scientists at NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory sent their final data uplink to the Opportunity rover on Mars. Over this connection, via the Deep Space Network, the American jazz singer Billie Holiday crooned "I'll Be Seeing You," a song that closes with the lines...

To me, "Billie Holiday crooned..." suggests that a real audio recording of music was used to modulate the carrier in some way either direct AM or FM, or as digital data via more standard DSN data encoding schemes.

**update:** I've just read in the New York Times' [NASA Rover Finally Bites the Dust on Mars After 15 Years](https://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2019/02/13/science/ap-us-sci-mars-rover.html):

> Flight controllers tried numerous times to make contact, and sent one final series of recovery commands Tuesday night, along with one last wake-up song, Billie Holiday's "I'll Be Seeing You," in a somber exercise that brought tears to team members' eyes. There was no response from space, only silence.

To me, "...one last wake-up song..." suggests this is more frequent than I'd originally thought. In that case we don't need a specific number, but instead just a better understanding of **How many non-crewed deep-space destinations have had intentional broadcasts of music from Earth?**

Comment: related but different: [How did NASA's Deep Space Network encode and broadcast music to Opportunity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34185/12102)

Comment: Theremin concert in 2001 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Age_Message

Comment: @A.Rumlin That's great! I think this question will end up with more than one answer, would you consider posting that as one? Those are indeed specific destinations, and certainly had no *Earth* crew, so they definitely count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"First Theremin Concert for Extraterrestrials" in 2001 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Age_Message

> Three theremin performers from the Moscow Theremin Center – Lydia Kavina, Yana Aksenova, and Anton Kerchenko – were invited to perform seven songs selected by students. The program included two Russian folk songs and works by Beethoven, Vivaldi, Saint-Saëns, Rakhmaninov, and Gershwin. Kavina submitted recordings of her performance, but Aksenova and Kerchenko performed live – a 70-meter radar dish had been specially modified to accept input from theremins. Each performance lasted about fifteen minutes. The First Theremin Concert for Extraterrestrials was the world's first musical Active SETI broadcast, and was sent seven years before NASA's Across the Universe message.

Targets:

```
 star & constellation    ly  type  kW  transmission date     (est. reception) 

HD 197076   Delphinus   68.5  G5V  126    August 29, 2001  February 2070
HD 95128    Ursa Major  45.9  G0V   96  September 3, 2001      July 2047
HD 50692    Gemini      56.3  G0V   96  September 3, 2001  December 2057
HD 126053   Virgo       57.4  G1V   96  September 3, 2001   January 2059
HD 76151    Hydra       55.7  G2V   96  September 4, 2001       May 2057
HD 193664   Draco       57.4  G3V   96  September 4, 2001   January 2059
```

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Across_the_Universe_(message)

> **Across the Universe** is an interstellar radio message (IRM) consisting of the song "Across the Universe" by The Beatles that was transmitted on 4 February 2008, at 00:00 UTC by NASA in the direction of the star Polaris. This transmission was made using a 70-meter dish in the Deep Space Network's (DSN) Madrid Deep Space Communication Complex, located in Robledo, near Madrid, Spain.