# What was the last message Opportunity sent?

Tags: communication, opportunity

Everybody seems to be abuzz with the idea that Opportunity's last transmission was "My battery is low and it's getting dark." Of course, that would be a human interpretation of some sort of diagnostics check. However, as far as I can tell, the only source for that information is a [single tweet](https://twitter.com/JacobMargolis/status/1095436913173880832). According to the [official Opportunity update log](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/rover-status/opportunity/recent/all/?y=2018) on sols 5108 to 5111, (June 7, 2018 - June 10, 2018):

> The project team is listening each day during the expected fault window time with the Deep Space Network (DSN). No signal has been detected since the last normal communication on Sol 5111 (June 10, 2018). It is expected that we will not hear from the rover until the storm subsides over the rover site.

So the last transmission was some sort of "normal communication". According to a [news post from the Opportunity team](https://mars.nasa.gov/news/8348/opportunity-hunkers-down-during-dust-storm/), there was a transmission on June 10 which included atmospheric opacity data , so there may be some truth to the "it's getting dark" part. But it doesn't say anything about battery level.

So that brings me to my question: What data was included in Opportunity's final transmission?

Comment: "I don't think they've seen me yet, switching to stealth mode."

Comment: https://twitter.com/elclimo/status/1095852348658700289/photo/1

Comment: Some related info here, but no definitive technical transmission. 
 https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43466/was-opportunitys-last-message-to-earth-my-battery-is-low-and-its-getting-dark

Comment: See also: https://twitter.com/doug_ellison/status/1096500125432606720

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34180/198

Comment: here's oppy's last message, "Time to end 14 years of NASA working the crap out of me!"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Planetary Data System](https://an.rsl.wustl.edu/su/i5P9Kbf4L7):

> Opportunity is currently in the midst of a severe dust storm though all subsystems are still operating as expected in RAM mode as of the Sol 5111 UHF pass. Solar array energy is approximately 22 W-hrs, with a measured tau of 10.8. This Tau measurement is the highest ever recorded from a ground station on the planet Mars. Dust factor was previously estimated at 3.27 as of Sol 5108.
>
> With analysis from the data from the Sol 5111 downlink, we expected the rover to enter a low power fault mode very soon after that point in time.

Translated in to "human" terms: It's getting dark, and my batteries are running low.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the average power was between 300-900 watt-hours, so 22 is indeed quite low. Thanks for finding this. Also, I like the statement at the top: "Tau Value is NOT a Typographical Error".

Comment: @ahiijny nice link! I've just asked [Opportunity's last tau was 10.8; what does that mean and how is tau defined and measured?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34257/12102)